# LogCat message: The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a application where I am using Google Play Service ads Api for showing add,everything is working fine but I am getting a the message :

**The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included**

Please help.....

Comment: you need to reference google play services library project in your android project properly

Comment: I have already added the library project,and the ads are showing correctly but in the logCat I am getting this message

Comment: do you have the updated  version of the library project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its because of buggy GPLAY Services v13, they'll introduce new version soon you can view this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=704#c14) for more information

Comment: then should I publish the app with this bug?

Comment: admob will work normally, if you're having Plus one button then it'll not work unless the bug been worked out by google, decision is yours

Comment: then you can publish your app

Comment: So I can't publish my app because of Google not fixiing the bug??? I tried to schedule my app release to teh 24th December put the G+ Integration isn't working